# WCF Single Service Implemation - Multiple Behaviours

Tags: wcf

I have an IIS hosted WCF service that I need to expose to two client types, external (basicHttp legacy) and internal (wsHttp WCF). For the external client I want to impose a more strict throttling configuration. It seems that the throttling config  such as:

```
<serviceThrottling 
     maxConcurrentCalls="30" 
     maxConcurrentSessions="1000" 
     maxConcurrentInstances="30" />
```

can only be applied as a service behavior and not as an endpoint behavior. This means that I'll need to create two separate .svc files, which would resolve to the same .cs file, such as follows:

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="x.xServiceBehavior">
     <endpoint 
          address="~/xService.svc" 
          binding="wsHttpBinding" 
          contract="xService.IxService"/>
</service>

<service behaviorConfiguration="xService.ThrottledxServiceBehavior">
     <endpoint 
          address="~/ThrottledxService.svc" 
          binding="basicHttpBinding" 
          contract="x.xService.IxService"/>
</service>
```

Is that the best way to achieve what I'm after or is there an better way?

Thanks

Rob.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have done it looks correct to achieve a different service behaviorConfiguration for the two different bindings. It may be possible to achieve the same effect while avoiding having two .svc files, but the way above will work fine so why rock the boat! :)